# Change cell value of excel file in c#?

Tags: c#, excel

I have excel file and loaded in `c#` windows applciaction.

I want to change the value in excel cell e.g change value in cell a10 and save the file.

The excel file contains multiple sheets.

Any help in this regard?

```
var ds = new DataSet();
            ds = Parse(fileName);

static DataSet Parse(string fileName)
        {
            string connectionString = string.Format("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", fileName);


            DataSet data = new DataSet();

            foreach (var sheetName in GetExcelSheetNames(connectionString))
            {
                using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    var dataTable = new DataTable();
                    string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", sheetName);
                    con.Open();
                    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                    data.Tables.Add(dataTable);
                }
            }

            return data;
        }


        static string[] GetExcelSheetNames(string connectionString)
        {
            OleDbConnection con = null;
            DataTable dt = null;
            con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();
            dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

            if (dt == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            String[] excelSheetNames = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
            int i = 0;

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                excelSheetNames[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                i++;
            }

            return excelSheetNames;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us your code and where you fail.

Comment: now all excel file is in ds so how to get excel cell name

Comment: Does your excel sheet have a header row?

Answer (score 0):

To specify that your sheet has a header row or not, modify the connection string to specify the `HDR` value. Refer to http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/ for more information.

If your sheet has a header row, you can refer the columns by the header.

If your sheet does not have a header row use F1, F2, F3.... Fn where F1 is the first selected column. If you don't specify where to start, then column A, B, C correspond to F1, F2, F3 etc.

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]                    <-- Column A=F1, B=F2 etc.
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$B1:Z100]             <-- Column B=F1, C=F2 etc.
```

Now once you know how to refer to the columns, rest should be easy. Create an OledbCommand object and execute your command.

```
UPDATE [Sheet1$A1:A1] SET F1='TestValue1'          <-- trick to update only one cell

UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET F1='TestValue1', F2 = 'some value 2' WHERE WhateverCondition
```

I haven't ever tried with Datasets and DataAdapters with excel oledb, but logically that should work too because in the end they all drill down to `Command` object.